# Footer to go over/cover the bottom of an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, footer

New to coding - can you help me place a footer over the iframe? It needs to cover the dark grey footer that is currently in the iframe, and also needs to be responsive if the page is zoomed in or out. It can be dark gray for now.

Attached is the current coding.

Thanks for your help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    }
iframe {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=71689B83CE6D0B52&resid=71689B83CE6D0B52%217352&authkey=AOXRS7b8IrWU4Qs&em=2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
  }
  iframe {
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
  }
  .footer{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 50px;
     background: black;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=71689B83CE6D0B52&resid=71689B83CE6D0B52%217352&authkey=AOXRS7b8IrWU4Qs&em=2"></iframe>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however do you know of a way to always cover the footer? When you zoom in to say 500% on the browser (Chrome), you can see the footer that I'm trying to cover. Regards

Comment: I check it with my chrome. Yepe it cover iframe footer without any issue. Just try give 30px for the footer height.

Comment: Thanks, but when I zoom in to 500% you can still see the icons in the original footer, also it does not work well in IE.